# AngularJs MemoryLeak Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks

I want to display a custom html on a angularjs page with the following service:

```
app.service('automaticFunctions', function ($timeout) {

this.init = function initAutomaticFunctions(scope, $elem, attrs) {
    switch (scope.content.type) {
        case 'list':
            ....
            break;  
        case 'scroll':
            ....
            break;
        case 'custom':

        function updateFrameContent() {
            var frame = $($elem).find(".customFrame")[0];

            if (scope.content.frameType === "url") {
                scope.content.ngHide.frameContent = true;
                scope.content.ngHide.frameUrl = false;
                frame.src = scope.content.frameUrl;
            }
            if (scope.content.frameType === "html") {
                scope.content.ngHide.frameUrl = true;
                scope.content.ngHide.frameContent = false;
                frame.onload = function () {
                    frame.contentWindow.document.write(scope.content.frameContent);
                    frame.onload = null;
                };
                frame.src = "";
                // frame = null;
            }
        }

            scope.$watchGroup(['content.frameType', 'content.frameContent', 'content.frameUrl'], function () {
                updateFrameContent();
            });
            updateFrameContent();
            break;
    }

}
});
```

I call the init procedure from a directive for 10 to 20 times when I route between pages.

I have a massive memory leak and I don't know handle the frame variable. If I set it to null, there is no memory leak but the content is not displayed.

Comment: Have you tried to set the `frame` variable only once and just reuse it like you do in the `init` fnc. You can declare the `frame` variable above the `init` fnc, and edit the line `var frame = $($elem).find(".customFrame")[0];` to:

`if (!frame) frame = $($elem).find(".customFrame")[0];`

Comment: is not ok, because every time in init function, frame var  has different value

Comment: Have you checked if you have any Detached Nodes when profiling the application?
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Comment: Yes, i have Detached Nodes..

Answer (score 0):

> I have a massive memory leak and I don't know handle the `frame` variable. If I set it to `null`, there is no memory leak but the content is not displayed.

Use the [`$destroy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#event-$destroy) event to release the `frame` object:

```
    function updateFrameContent() {
        var frame = $($elem).find(".customFrame")[0];

        scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
            frame = null;
        });

        if (scope.content.frameType === "url") {
            scope.content.ngHide.frameContent = true;
            scope.content.ngHide.frameUrl = false;
            frame.src = scope.content.frameUrl;
        }
```

WIth the AngularJS framework, directives such as `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, `ng-view`, etc. create and destroy DOM elements and child scopes. Use the `$destroy` event to include any tear-down code needed.

For information, see [AngularJS $scope API Reference - Events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#events).